# Using Wicket StringResource inside javascript - How To or Best Practice

Tags: javascript, wicket, wicket-6

I have a question regarding wickets i18n features. All my text I publish to my webpage is provided by StringResourceModel or ResourceModel so I can easily switch the locale language. Works good!

Now I have some Javascript that produces Text that is shown to the user. I would like this text to have the same i18n features I have with wicket.

I had a similar problem with images referenced inside Javascript and CSS. I solved this with the use of mountSharedResources. Is there something like this for Strings?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

cheers
Reinhard

Comment: Do you need the full power of StringResourceModel (e.g. property expressions) or simple localized strings? It could make a difference as to the proposed solution. Either way however, I don't think there exists client-side Javascript functionality to look-up Wicket resource strings directly.

Comment: Does this have to be pure JavaScript? If not, you could just create the IDs used by StringResourceModel and fetch the localized messages by refreshing a label using Ajax. Just a quick and unproven idea...

Comment: Depening on the amount of strings you want to pull in your javascript, you might want to create a mapped `IResource` that provides the `String` based on the parameters on the url. You could for example load them with ajax. Or, you could source the javascript from Wicket and pass the strings as arguments.